# redirecting unmatched pattern to another page using redirectmatch

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

if url is like this

```
   http://samplexxxx.com/some keywords/  it has to redirect to                                 

   http://samplexxxx.com/ap/search.php?searchterm=$1
```

for that i had written like this

```
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]*)/ http://samplexxxx .com/ap/search.php?searchterm=$1  

     it was working fine
```

but here matching keywords should not ap i.e

```
                       http://samplexxxx.com/ap/
```

so here redirection should done other than ap keywords then how do i need to change the regular expression matching pattern.

Comment: RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!ap/)[^/]+)/ http://samplexxxx .com/ap/search.php?searchterm=$1  
 when i used this other directories such as http://samplexxxx .com/images/image1.jpg,http://samplexxxx .com/adimages/adimage1.jpg url's also get redirected to search page so changed it to check negative lookahead in multiple expressions like this    
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!ap|adimages|images|tamil/)[^/]*)/ http://everydaypopcorn.com/ap/search.php?searchterm=$1  then it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookahead in your regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!ap/)[^/]+)/ http://samplexxxx .com/ap/search.php?searchterm=$1
```

Comment: it's working but i had another url format in my site i.e http://sample.com/adimages/indexcenterad1.jpg this also redirecting here redirection should occur only for http://exeminds.com/some keywords other than ap/

Comment: Didn't get your comment. You wrote you wanted to exclude `/ap/` and that's what answer does. If you want to change requirements then edit your question and provide some more examples.